# How to convert a 2D dataframe into a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, correlation

I am working on a dataset and I found out the correlation between every pair of features. The 2D data frame looks like this

[image]

I have to iterate over all these values to select those values which are greater than some threshold to select important features.

I think array would be convenient to handle in this case instead. How to convert this into a 2D array?

It will  look somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: `dataframe.values` will return a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dataframe.values`:
What `df.values` basically does is that gives you the raw NumPy ndarray without the indexes.